# how to increase the font-size without making it thicker

Tags: css

I have few characters that need to be increased in size(height). I have used the font size property which gives me the desired result but makes it thick too.
How can I remove the thickness that has been applied?

I have tried using font-weight but I haven't noticed any difference.

**HTML**

```
 <div class="row collapse">
                    <div class="four columns">
                        <label for="txtBirthMonth">Date:</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="two columns collapse">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthMonth" runat="server" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                    <div class="one column">
                        <p class="splCharacter">/</p>
                       </div>
                    <div class="two columns">
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtBirthDay" runat="server" MaxLength="2"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                       <div class="one columns">
                        <p class="splCharacter">/</p>
                       </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.splCharacter {
    font-size: 3em;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

[image]

Comment: that's not "bold". That's just a natural consequence of making your characters 3x larger than normal: they're bigger, so they're thicker and appear "bolder" compared to the original size.

Comment: It's not bold... It's just bigger.  Add font-weight: bold; and you will see it become bold.  Change it to font-weight: normal; and you will get the same as what you already have.  When you increase the size of a font it increases proportionately, meaning you increase the height and the width of the text.  Doing so means your text will naturally become a little fatter.

Comment: ok. Sorry bold was not appropriate to use here.
What I mean to say is thicker. So is there a way to make them not look so thick but achieve the desired result

Comment: Use a different font, something that is "light" or narrow".

For example you have Helvetica Neue, then you have Helvetica Neue Light, Helvetica Neue Extra Light, Helvetica Neue Bold.  etc. 

The font you are using is the font you are using, you can make it bold, you can make it italics, you can underline it or even change it's line height.  Altering it's default thickness is altering the font itself, which is impossible with CSS outside of declaring a different font(which isn't actually altering a font).

Comment: If it looks awkward then maybe you should just keep everything the same font-size.

Comment: You can also play with color. If you make `color: grey` it will make less noticeable than black.

Comment: @Michael Your suggestion of using a different font was useful too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use the font-size property as you have done, that does not increase the font-weight just the size.

If you don't like the font-weight at the increased size then you should also add a rule to decrease the weight, e.g.:

```
.splCharacter {
font-size: 3em;
font-weight: 200;
margin: 0; // The value is zero so you don't need to specify the unit.
}
```

Of course, the font you are using must support this reduced weight or this rule will have no effect.

Comment: Added margin as I was trying to override some other margin it was inheriting.

Comment: My point was that if the value is zero, you don't need to declare that the unit is pixels. 0px is the same as 0em, 0miles, 0houses or 0monkeys, so you only need to declare 0.

Comment: I completely misunderstood it. Got it now.